# Why the tunnel Xdmcp+ssh don't work?

Tags: ssh, x11, socat, xdmcp

I want to tunnel via ssh a Xdmcp protocol. To access sicure to a remote login.
An easy solution can be openvpn, but I want to try socat+ssh first.
The server is Solaris 10 The client is Slackware 15.

On Client

```
ssh -L 6667:localhost:6667 192.168.201.200
```

on server

```
socat tcp4-listen:6667,reuseaddr,fork UDP:192.168.201.200:177
```

on Client

```
sudo socat udp4-listen:177,reuseaddr,fork tcp:localhost:6667
```

Now on client i run Xephyr and...

```
Xephyr -query localhost -screen 1024x767  :2
```

[image]

Using Xdcmp directly without tunnel works, but is unsafe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found this workaround

```
ssh -X -C 192.168.201.200 -t /usr/X11/bin/amd64/Xephyr :1 -query localhost
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are telling Xephyr to send its queries to localhost, it will probably specify the network address of the display in XDMCP packets as 127.0.0.1. Your socat->ssh->socat pipeline presumably won't change the contents of the packet.

(I'm not sure if such a protocol conversion from UDP to TCP and back to UDP will work without any harmful side effects, but I'll assume it will.)

And so the display manager on Solaris gets a message: "Hello, I'm a X11 display at 127.0.0.1:2. Are you willing to manage me?". **Assuming that XDMCP support is enabled at Solaris end**, and the XDMCP negotiation is successful, this would lead to the display manager making a classic X11 connection for the purpose of displaying a graphical login window to TCP port 6002 (based on the display number)... on 127.0.0.1, i.e. *on the Solaris host*. This obviously won't reach the Slackware host at all.

(In practice, I would expect a Solaris 10 system to default to "no XDMCP access allowed", but I assume the necessary configuration has been done.)

You might get somewhere if you also set up a SSH remote TCP forwarding from the Solaris host's port 6002 to local port 6002 on the Slackware host:

```
 ssh -L 6667:localhost:6667 -R 6002:localhost:6002 192.168.201.200
```

But Xephyr is a modern X11 server, so it might not even listen for incoming TCP connections by default. You might need to explicitly tell it to listen for incoming TCP connections:

```
Xephyr -listen tcp -query localhost -screen 1024x767 :2
```

With these changes, and assuming the Solaris side is set up correctly to allow XDMCP, you might have a chance of this working. Maybe. I would not hold my breath, though.

One possible problem might be if the XDMCP protocol relays the display name as just `:2`, then the display manager on the Solaris side would probably assume that Unix socket at `/tmp/.X11-unix/X2` could be used to connect to the querying display server. If the Solaris host has a modern enough `sshd`, you could forward that too... but the use of Unix sockets would cause any X11 application (including the display manager) to assume that the display is in fact a local one, and try to activate X11 protocol extensions relying on shared memory access to the X11 server. Since the applications and the server are located in different computers, shared memory access would be obviously impossible.

Then you would have any X11 fonts needed by Solaris's Motif window manager available to your Xephyr X11 server...

Comment: Thanks but give me black screen, on Solaris 10 xdcmp listen only on udp

Comment: After a successful XDMCP negotiation over UDP, the X Display Manager process on Solaris should be **connecting to** your Xephyr using TCP. Since you've tricked the Solaris to thinking the XDMCP connection comes from localhost, it will be your responsibility to forward the TCP connection from Solaris back to Slackware. Will the Slackware system allow the connection, and **is Xephyr listening for TCP connections**? If that connection cannot happen, then a black screen is all you get.

Comment: XDMCP using only udp, on Solaris I see this https://pastebin.com/raw/uUZgPv7k, as you can see is only on udp, on Slackware same thing

Comment: Using this line works after set reverse -R with ssh `Xephyr -listen tcp -query 192.168.201.200 -port 6667 -screen 1024x767 :2` but is not tunneled and all clear

Comment: No, it's not tunneled. You will see a TCP connection from some high-numbered port on Solaris to port 6002 on Slackware. That's a legacy, unencrypted X11 connection. Not recommended for use today, unless you absolutely must work with systems much older than Solaris 10.